# Default route pattern not working in Program.cs if we use hyphens by using Route attribute. What is the issue?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

To go with SEO friendly URL structure (Hyphens) I added following code to action. I had to add this attribute for all of my actions.

```
 [Route("title-case-converter")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {}
```

At program.cs I wanted to show this page as default.

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=title-case-converter}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

The routing is working. But showing the page as default is not working. If I remove the Route attribute from action and change  controller=titlecaseconverter its working (My view name is titlecaseconverter). What is the issue here?

Comment: You wrote: _My view name is titlecaseconverter._ But according to the code above your view name is *title-case-converter*. So, what is correct one? Are you sure you use the `asp.net-mvc-5`, but not `asp.net-core`? The [IActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iactionresult?view=aspnetcore-7.0) interface is declared in the `asp.net-core`.

Comment: @Victor i am learning mvc. Sorry. Its mvc core. My current view name is titlecaseconverter and i want it to appear in url as title-case-converter.  I updated the tags

Comment: So, do you want the controller name will be `title-case-converter` and the view name will be `title-case-converter` instead of `Index` ? This is what I see from the code above. It is correct?

Comment: Your default routing doesn't look reasonable. Your controller name is `titlecaseconverter`, why are you adding a hyphen in the default route? This will not find your corresponding controller.

Comment: In addition, according to the description of [the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#mixed-routing-attribute-routing-vs-conventional-routing): Actions that define attribute routes cannot be reached through the conventional routes and vice-versa. Any route attribute on the controller makes all actions in the controller attribute routed.

Comment: @Chen: The post question contains lot of inconsistencies. The post author creates confusion by using the same name `titlecaseconverter` in controller and action method. But, actually the controller name, as part of the route, can contain hyphens. For example, by applying `[Route("title-case-converter")]` attribute to the class.

Comment: Hi @Victor, I know that, but does this not match the idea of `{controller/action}`?

Answer (score 0):

If it is necessary to declare the action method as default define the [`Route`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis) attribute as below:

```cs
[Route("~/")]
[Route("title-case-converter")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @Victor, I think that it should be `[Route("~/")]`, not `[Route("~\")]`.

Comment: @Chen: Thank you. This was usual typo. I Fixed it. :)

Comment: @PrageethLiyanage, did you try solution above?